# FTP File Upload - Filename Encoding Error

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-commons-net

I'm using apache's commons-net 3.5 to upload files to a remote FTP server, and setting the connection encoding to UTF-8 like below, before openning the connection.

```
ftpClient.setAutodetectUTF8(true);
ftpClient.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
```

And this is the part that sends the file

```
private void uploadFile(byte[] data, String path, String fileName, FTPClient ftpClient) throws IOException {
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    boolean uploadSuccess = ftpClient.storeUniqueFile(fileName, new  ByteArrayInputStream(data));
```

Here is the problem; when sending files whose name contains Turkish characters, the result file is named incorrectly. Like,

```
Kimlikş.pdf -> KimlikÅ.pdf
```

But if I use [ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/), everything works fine. Did anyone have this before? The data ships incrorrectly from my side. I monitored the traffic with Microsoft Network Monitor. Here is the raw request:

```
FTP FTP:Request from Port 62642,'STOR KimlikÅ.pdf'  {TCP:5879, IPv4:134}
```

Comment: make sure you're using the appropriate character set everywhere, especially on the remote system. sending a UTF-8 filename from your client is pointless if the remote filesystem is (say) using win-1252.

Comment: `ftpClient.setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: @Mark, I'm using the same character set on the server-side also.

Comment: @Joop, I'll try your suggestion as soon as I'm able. thanks to all for comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there was a bug with apache's commons-net, so I migrated to ftp4j and the problem was no more.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.sauronsoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>ftp4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use WinSCP - it was working like a charm.

https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

no FileZilla, no TotalCommander - only WinSCP.

- and by copy again (for example I had about 6k files and only 50 with cyrilic) only give at question prompt "no to all" and WinSCP copies only left files. great !

5 stars to the free software !